# Observable.FromEvent with event args that have the in modifier cause exception

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm using a 3rd party library which has an event\event handler, which I'd like to convert to
an observable. The event handler delegate wants a struct, with the in keyword. This causes an exception:

System.ArgumentException - Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

from

```
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegateInternal(System.Type delegateType, object firstArgument, System.DelegateBindingFlags bindingFlags) Line 556    C#
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type delegateType, object target) Line 534 C#
    System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.ReflectionUtils.CreateDelegate<Test.TheDelegate>(object o, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) Line 18 C#
```

If I remove the in from the arguments, It works as expected.
I'm at a loss to understand why? Is even possible to do?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

Test test = new();

Start();
test.TriggerEvent();
test.TriggerEvent();

void Start()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Start");
    var o = Observable.FromEvent<Test.TheDelegate, SomeStruct>
        (h => test.TheEvent += h, 
         h => test.TheEvent -= h)
                      .Subscribe(OnNext);
}

void OnNext(SomeStruct s) => Debug.WriteLine("OnNext");

public class Test
{
    public delegate void TheDelegate(in SomeStruct o);

    // Without the in (or ref) keyword, no exception
    //public delegate void TheDelegate(SomeStruct o);

    public event TheDelegate? TheEvent;

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        SomeStruct s = new();
        TheEvent?.Invoke(s);
        Debug.WriteLine("Event Fired");
    }
}

public struct SomeStruct
{ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the `ArgumentException` at run-time. To solve it, you could use the `Observable.FromEvent` overload that has an extra `conversion` parameter:

```
public static IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
    Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion,
    Action<TDelegate> addHandler,
    Action<TDelegate> removeHandler);
```

Usage:

```
var observable = Observable.FromEvent<Test.TheDelegate, SomeStruct>
(
    action => (in SomeStruct arg) => action(arg),
    h => test.TheEvent += h,
    h => test.TheEvent -= h
);
var subscription = observable.Subscribe(OnNext);
```

The `conversion` converts an `Action<SomeStruct>` to a `Test.TheDelegate`. Contrary to the simpler overload, the validity of the conversion is checked at compile-time.

Comment: This works, and I learned something!

Comment: You're a legend, Theo. I tried to get that overload to work and struggled with it. Seems so simple now that I see that answer. Genius!

Comment: @Enigmativity ha ha! I struggled to make it work too!